# Windows-1250 in Eclipse Console

Tags: java, encoding, bufferedreader

I have got a file in `Windows-1250`.

I would like to print this file line by line but in Eclipse console I cannot see diacritic signs.

I was trying to make changes in Common tab in `run configuration` but it gives no results.

I use

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `InputStreamReader` or anything that allows specifying the charset:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(fileName), "Windows-1250"));
```

Answer (score 0):

may be try to set encoding like this:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "Windows-1250");
out.println(message);
```

may be this helps.

Comment: no, does not work. but maybe problem is with reading file cause for example i can print "ź" with normal System.out.println properly...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't programmed in java for a while but maybe [this class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) does what you need? 
It allows to set charset

The [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) of the class you use tells you how to use it.